# OnListItemClick is not working correctly

Tags: java, android, listview

In my app I have a class that extends ListActivity and uses a ListView. My onListItemClick method just does not want to work. Inside the method it has to determine whether the item being clicked is Workout A or Workout B. Here is the code:

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        Long rowId = id;

        Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.fetchNote(rowId);

        String activity = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(StrongDbAdapter.WORKOUT_STATE));

        if(activity == "Workout A"){
            workoutAA = true;
        }else if(activity == "Workout B"){
            workoutAA = false;
        }


        if(workoutAA == true){
            Intent i = new Intent(this, WorkoutEditA.class);
            i.putExtra(StrongDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
        }else if(activity == "Workout B"){
            Intent i = new Intent(this, WorkoutEditB.class);
            i.putExtra(StrongDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`activity.equals( "Workout A")`. when string comparison use `equals()`

Another approach to avoid NullPointerException would be

```
"Workout A".equals(acitivty)
```